# jQuery find() - exclude $(this) element

Tags: jquery

Basically I'm trying to do a find and then run an effect, but I want to exclude the owner element. This is what I have at the moment:

```
$('li.main').click(function(){
    $(this).parents('.content').find('li.main').not(this).removeClass('active');
    $(this).parents('.content').find('li.subs').not(this).slideUp();

    $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
    $(this).parent().next('li.subs').slideToggle();
});
```

Doesn't quite work. Anybody know how to do it?

Comment: Which part isn't working - the find or the manipulation?  That is, can you verify that the 'find' is selecting the elements you want?

Comment: Please define "Doesn't quite work". Can you reproduce it in a fiddle and share with us?

Comment: How about a jsFiddle or the HTML that goes with this?

Comment: Basically what's happening is when I click on an item, it perform the effect (i.e sets class to 'active' and does the slide animation). Now when I click on that same item again, it does the exact same thing - what it should do is remove the class 'active' and slide up.

Comment: @GSTAR you should update your question with the explanation from your comment, also basic HTML structure of the elements in question may help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('li.main').click(function(){
    var item = $(this), allItems = item.parents('.content').find('li.main');
    if(!item.hasClass('active')){
        allItems = allItems.not(item);
        item.parent().addClass('active');
        item.parent().next('li.subs').slideDown();
    }
    allItems.removeClass('active');
    allItems.slideUp();
});
```

Comment: Not really: not accepts DOM elements as well http://api.jquery.com/not/ 

Consider updating your answer to avoid getting downvoted

Comment: My bad. Updated answer with a possible solution.